# What kind of medical cover for a South African visa to stay for more than 6 months?

Tags: health-insurance, south-africa

I am a PhD student at a US university and plan to be in SA for a year to do my research. As per the visa requirements, I need to get a "*Proof of medical cover renewed annually for the period of study with a medical scheme registered in terms of the Medical Schemes Act"*. As someone told me that the SA long term stay (more than 6 months) visa require a particular type of health insurance. Does anybody here have any insight into purchasing a health cover plan for applying for South Africa professional/work/research visa? Any sugeestions on the best plans in the market will be much appreciated.

Best.
Sonal